# python ldaptor inmemory Syntax Error

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OpenLdapServer.py", line 6, in <module>
  from ldaptor.inmemory import fromLDIFFile
  File "C:\Users\RnD_01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\ldaptor-16.0.0-py3.6.egg\ldaptor\inmemory.py", line 59
  raise ldaperrors.LDAPEntryAlreadyExists, self._children[rdn_str].dn
                                        ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know why there is an syntax error.

Comment: Probably the previous line is missing a closing parentheses or square bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ldaptor` is not supporting python3, it is write in python2, you are trying to run the code in python 3 environment, the syntax of raise exceptions in python 2 vs 3 is different:

Python2:

```
raise IOError, "file error"
```

or

```
raise IOError("file error")
```

Python3:

```
raise IOError("file error")
```

Please refer to this issue: https://github.com/twisted/ldaptor/issues/55